# How do you add multiple watermarks?

Tags: watermark

I want to put 2 watermarks on one document, but it only prints my last watermark.

I don't want to add 2 lines to 1 watermark. I need 1 going horizontal at the top of my page and one going diagonally across the whole page.

This is what I'm currently using:

```
\special{!userdict begin /bop-hook{gsave 180 20 translate 90 rotate /Times-Roman findfont 90 scalefont setfont 0 0 moveto 0.7 setgray (HEADER) show grestore}def end}

\special{!userdict begin /bop-hook{gsave 320 100 translate 75 rotate /Times-Roman findfont 180 scalefont setfont 0 0 moveto 0.7 setgray (BODY) show grestore}def end}
```

Comment: The reason why it only prints the last watermark is that the second special redefines `bop-hook`, overwriting the previous definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{eso-pic,graphicx,showframe}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{\makebox[\paperwidth]{This is at the top, centred}}}%
  \AtPageCenter{\rotatebox{52}{\makebox[0pt]{\Huge This is diagonally across the page}}}}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using background package is also an option where scale, angle, position, color, (x, y) shift can be controlled by users.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}

\begin{document}
This is a text.
\SetBgContents{This watermark is at the top}      % a watermark
\SetBgPosition{current page.center}
\SetBgAngle{0}                                    % rotate
\SetBgColor{blue}                                 % color
\SetBgScale{1.5}                                  % scale
\SetBgHshift{0}                                   % location x=0 for center
\SetBgVshift{9cm} 

\makeatletter                % For a second watermark on the same page then repeat
\AddEverypageHook{%          % Or AddThispageHook for one time only                     
\SetBgContents{This watermark is diagonally laid} % a watermark
\SetBgPosition{current page.center}
\SetBgAngle{45}                                   % rotate
\SetBgColor{red}                                  % color
\SetBgScale{1.5}                                  % scale
\SetBgHshift{0}                                   % location x=0 for center
\SetBgVshift{0}
\bg@material}
\end{document}
```

[image]