# Inserting an A1 image into an A4 document whilst maintaining page numbers?

Tags: graphics, formatting, page-numbering, pdfpages, width

I'm a bit new to LaTeX so sorry if this is obvious. I'm trying to insert a large image (which I have created a pdf version of) into an A4 document. I have tried using pdfpages and fitpaper=true to insert the image but then the page number is displayed in the middle of the document, as it still treats the page as an A4 size. I have trawled the internet and found a method for changing the size of a single sheet in the document into an A3, which works fine, but I get issues when I try to adapt it for an A1. Below is the code I am currently using:

```
\newpage
\begingroup
\advance\textwidth\pdfpagewidth
\hsize=\textwidth\linewidth=\hsize\columnwidth=\hsize
\pdfpagewidth=4\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=2\pdfpageheight

\hfill\includegraphics[scale=0.80]{./Images/image.pdf}\hspace*{\fill}

\newpage
\endgroup
```

I believe the issue is due to the workable page space that hasn't been taken into account when I changed the physical size of the page.

Alternatively if you use pdfpages:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,scale=0.8,fitpaper=true,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{./Images/image.pdf}
```

The image appears correctly as an A1 drawing on an A1 sheet in an otherwise A4 document, but the page number does not display correctly on the bottom as a footer.

If anyone can give any guidance that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I take it you want to fill the entire A1 page (including margins) with the A4 image.  If so, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136900/insert-a-full-page-image

Comment: No, I think the OP wants to insert an Al image into an A4 document. What I'm not clear about is whether this should ideally be scaled to A4, scaled to A3 or left as A1 with a one-off out-sized page.

Comment: The image I'm inserting is a flow diagram, which I have produced on an A1 sheet. I need to insert the image as an A1 sheet into the A4 document. I can achieve this using pdfpages and fitpaper=true, but page numbering then becomes an issue. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: So you want to clip the image to remove the page number and scale it to use a new page number?    \includegraphics* will clip and    \resizebox will scale.

Comment: See also http://www.compuphase.com/electronics/folding.htm

Answer (score 2):

This works as is. The page number lines up with the page number from my source A1 page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcommand{\pcmd}[2]% #1 = width of working space, #2 = distance to page number
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\noindent%
\raisebox{-#2}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[#1][c]{\thepage}}%
\hspace{-#1}}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper=true,pagecommand={\pcmd{55.4cm}{80.8cm}}]%
{yourfile.pdf}

\end{document}
```

P.S. How the heck do you print something like this?

Comment: Thanks for your help John, but I just tried this code and the page numbers still aren't showing :/ Sorry.

P.S. Haha, I'm going to have to outsource the printing to the university's printing company (they can do A0 prints!)

Comment: BTW, does the A1 document already have margins?  On A1 paper the margins for scale=.8 are going to be huge!

Comment: Haha yeah it's just for an example - I'll change it so that the image fits nicely around the page numbering and/or headers.

Comment: With the last set of changes, I cam put the new page number directly on top of the page number in my A1 test file.  Interestingly, the font size is slightly different.

Comment: The font sizes were the same after all.  It was an optical illusion. BTW, have you tried running the MWE by itself (changing yourfile.pdf, of course)?

Comment: Hey John, yeah I've tried running the MWE but no page number. To be sure I tested it with a blank A1 drawing in case the number was being hidden some graphics/text, but didn't see anything.

Comment: Sigh.  The reason I asked is that if the top margin is too large it could push the page number off the bottom of the page.