# How do I add beautiful borders to the title page

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles

I want to add an attractive border to the title page alone. Please explain how I can do this?

Comment: Please be more specific. Exactly what result do you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want any border to envelope my title page. Any border will do the work.

Comment: Google for art borders, download one you like, then use it for background.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136900/insert-a-full-page-image

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. Moreover, a good border for your PhD thesis might not be the best choice for a romantic novel. I doubt very much that literally *any* border will do. Would a border consisting of cupids with bows and arrows *and* a border consisting of skulls and crossbones *both* be suitable? (I'm not suggesting using either for *any* document. Just pointing out that they would be borders.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use tikz to draw a simple border around your title page or add it to every page your like. You can change the line's shape and thickness or it's colour.

```
%pdflatex
\documentclass[A4]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\title{Title Page}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw [line width=1.0pt,rounded corners=10pt,]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (2.5cm,-3.5cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-3.5cm,2.5cm) $);       
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}

        \huge
        \textbf{Sample title page with border}

        \vspace{2.0cm}
        \LARGE
        \textbf{First name, Family name}

        \vfill

        \Large
         Date: Today
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but to me the title does not look centered.

Comment: @Sigur I don't know but I think It's because it is a book style with gutter on the right.

Answer (score 7):

I first found a "beautiful border" with google at http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-p0fCHoavj1c/UPi9y1VXINI/AAAAAAAAKy8/ULDyjBo1bK0/s1600/decorative+borders+and+frame.TIF, and saved it as frame.jpg.  Then, based on my answer at [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831), I scaled and inserted in on an a4 page.

While shown here with normal text on the first page, this method will work with whatever content (titlepage, etc.) that would otherwise appear on the first page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\begin{document}
\atxy{0.06in}{11.6in}{\includegraphics[scale=1.05]{frame}}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]