# How can I draw complex borders around all the pages of a document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, koma-script

I'm writing a document with the class `scrreprt`.

I would like to draw borders around the pages of the document. I found some examples on how to do this with TikZ, but the borders I would like to draw are too complex (at least for my tikz skills), and I'm searching other solutions. In particular, I would like to have a border similar to the one depicted in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKRAd.png) - second page from the top:

[image: example]

For the record, the boxes in the document are produced with the package [umrand](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/umrand), which is quite old - and in any case, I haven't found a way to use it to produce a border.

How can I produce a similar border on all the pages of the document?

Since I was asked to provide further details, here's what I tried. My idea was to try to get a box similar to the one shown above, and then find a way to use the code to draw the border around the page. Unfortunately the manual for the package umrand is in German, and the following code aborts because umrand.sty is not found:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{umrand}
\usepackage{niceframe}
\begin{document}

\RandBox{Test}
    font {\UB} [0pt]
    (\C5) ([\C1]) (\C4)
    ([\C2]) ([\CO])
    (\C6) ([\C3]) (\C7)

\end{document}
```

I then tried to obtain a similar image with tikz but failed miserably. I'm currently trying to draw it but I'm nowhere near. Will update if I can get the image in tikz.

Comment: If you have an image of the border, then something like this will work: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208977/how-do-i-add-beautiful-borders-to-the-title-page/209017#209017.  In that answer, change `\AddThispageHook` to `\AddEverypageHook`, and the result will carry across all pages of the document.

Comment: I believe the wallpaper package also does this.

Comment: Or the very new `scrlayer`. But in any case, you need to provide *how it should look like* somehow.

Comment: And some compilable code at least giving us the document structure for an example, but preferably showing what you've tried.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes your solution works with a few borders I found online (thanks!) but it is somehow suboptimal since it requires to have an image of the border of the right dimension. However, it's the solution that comes closer.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes it works, but again it is somehow non optimal. Anyway, better than nothing, thanks!

Comment: @Johannes_B Uhm, I thought I did. I would like to have a border around the page similar to the one depicted above - only, instead of a border around a box, I would like to have it around the page. If you think that this isn't clear enough, I'll try to be more specific in my description.

Comment: @cfr I didn't post a MWE because the document structure is really simple. It's just a scrreprt document with chapters and sections. As for what I tried, I will post some code after, but basically I managed to draw a linear border around the page with tikz - that's not even close to what I'm trying to achieve...

Comment: @greymatter0 Your question and desire is quite clear, for a human being, not LaTeX. You need to provide some picture, or 2 (tb, lr) or the code to do it in TikZ or PSTricks or picture mode. Placing the stuff is not really the issue here, but having something to place.

Comment: If the image is just slightly different aspect ratio from that needed, you can apply a `\scalebox{H-scale}[V-scale]{\includegraphics...}` to match the size.  On the other hand, there also exist complex "corners" (for lack of a better word). With these, you would place an appropriate corner in each of the four paper corners.

Comment: @greymatter0 No matter how simple the document is, a minimal working example saves time for the helpers.

Comment: Is the ```celtic``` package maybe of help? https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/celtic/celtic.pdf