# Fit book cover in first page

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I want to add to my LaTeX document ( [book] ) the cover of the first page. I have a problem though. It does not cover the entire page.

Here is the photo I want to add:

[image]

I use the geometry package with this configuration:

```
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm , a4paper]{geometry}
```

and as a command to include the picture I use:

```
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{cover_photo_new_version.jpg}  }
```

Well, the output is not the expected. This is what I get when I compile the document

[image]

and as we can all see it does not cover the page. I have read many questions here in TEX.SE but none of them fix my problem. Any way to fix it?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have not seen that..

Comment: No. I just want the first page to have my book cover not all the others.

Comment: My answer at that question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136900/insert-a-full-page-image/137166#137166, and surely others, certainly allow it to be done on a 1-page basis.  Just clear the page after setting the image, if you don't want any overlaid text.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That incgraph package did the job. Thank you for quick response. Feel free to close the topic.