# A5 booklet with single image as cover

Tags: graphics, covers

I need to assemble an A5 sized booklet, and I need the first page to be an image, stretched to fill the whole page. How can I accomplish this?

I have been looking around for the past two hours, messing with `incgraph` and whatnot, but I cannot obtain an acceptable result.

Simply using:

```
\includegraphics[width=\pagewidth]{image}
```

results in the image being off to the lower right, without filling the whole page.

```
\incgraph{image}
```

gives no errors but also displays no image.

I keep feeling there must be an easy way to do what I want, but I can't find it.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: This is what I have. As I said, it doesn't display any image, but also gives no error.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{incgraph}

\graphicspath{ {./Images/} }

\begin{document}

\incgraph{myCoverImage}

\section{section1}
Sample text

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This question has been here before :-)  pdfpages being the best answer imho: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163671/140011 
How is your question different?

Comment: I guess it's my fault for not scrolling that far down. Also, having to manually convert to pdf beforehand feels clumsy.

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando You don’t even have to convert the image first, you can just use the package `pdfpages` and say `\includepdf{myCoverImage.jpg}`. This package is also great for booklet creation.

Comment: @doncherry ... I would never have expected that to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there are a ton of different solutions shown over here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163671/140011

Regarding your problem: This is most likely a path problem - while `\includegraphics` would stop `\incgraph` silently fails. I would suggest to debug this this way:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\graphicspath{ {./Images/} }

\begin{document}
\incgraph{myCoverImage}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{myCoverImage}
\end{figure}

\section{section1}
Sample text
\end{document}
```

As an alternative solution to your original problem (thanks to @doncherry) you can to use this. Note that the pdfpages package is basically a case specific replacement for includegraphics so you might miss some options incgraph has.
Here is your example using the package pdfpages instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf{myCoverImage.jpg}
\end{document}
```