# crop margins but include pdfs full paper size

Tags: pdfpages, crop, fullpage

I want to include different kinds of PDFs. For one kind (a normal page just generated outside of LaTeX) I want the margins added by the crop package. But others are full size photos for which I want full paper size (no white borders around) because that is the point in the first place - not to add tiny white borders if the cutting is done a fraction of a millimeter larger than A4 (tiny bit smaller does not matter, losing one pixel cannot be recognized, adding one white dot to a dark photo definatelly will). So I think I need to be able to include logical pages that are set as such and pages that are not realy logical as they have the printing press' paper size as dimensions allready (and I know that 3mm of the picture will be cut off).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage[frame, width=216mm,height=303mm,center]{crop}
```

gives me the correct document for everything generated in LaTeX and also everything that is just A4 PDFs included without being sensitive to the fraction off a millimeter (not printing over the border into the margins to be cut). But including a PDF (that I allready made 216mm x 303mm in the generating software)

```
\includepdf[pages={1},pagecommand={
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Referenz: Gal Gadot} \label{img:2018050601}\glsadd{motivational:GadotGal} \thispagestyle{empty}
}]{img/GalGadot_Schulterblick.pdf}
```

puts it just as it would A4 and surrounds it with the 3mm white margin completely defeating the whole process.

Is crop even the correct package and either way - how do I include PDFs (or any graphics for that matter) not scaled just keeping it printing paper size in order to have the guy in the print job cut it guaranteing there will not be any white borders for the "full page graphics" included?

edit: maybee it gets more clear this way: I need to have a document for croping at the print job, therefore the paper in the generated PDF needs to be 216x303 instead of 210x297 (A4) but some PDFs included are already oversize 216x303 and must not be put into the centered A4 space. They are meant to be cut to avoid white borders after cutting the sheets at the print shop. Those must not be resized and centered as the crop package does with the code above.

Comment: If you want to fit a PDF page (cropped) into the text area, use \includegraphics with clip=true, one of the bb, viewport etc. options, and the undocumented page=... option.  For full page replacement, use \includepdf from pdfpages.

Comment: To crop and scale to full size, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136900/insert-a-full-page-image

Comment: That is not what I want (if I understand you at all). I want a page to be bigger than full page in a way. I need it to remain 216x303 in a A4 logical document to be printed on paper getting cut down to A4, therefore the pdf being 216x303 with crop placing the "logical document" centered and adding crop marks. I want the picture to be full page after being cut in the print shop, therefore it needs to be wider not only than textwidth but wider than paperwidth (of the logical document A4=210x297 => 216x303).

Comment: The whole "logical document" is correctly placed by the crop package allready, but the included PDF is also resized to A4 instead of remaining oversize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would do this by ensuring that the PDF boxes (/MediaBox, /BleedBox, and /TrimBox) are correctly set.

There isn't really a good automatic way of doing this in LaTeX.

So you need to set them up using the `\pdfpageattr` macro in `pdflatex`. The technique is slightly different for `lualatex` and `xelatex` if you use them.

In the following MWE, I also adjusted the trim marks to be more to my liking. Your printer may no need these marks at all. In which case you can just set your `/BleedBox` to be the same as your `/MediaBox` (216mm by 303mm).

In the picture below, the `/BleedBox` is blue and the `/TrimBox` is green.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[noinfo,width=230mm,height=317mm,center]{crop}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% better crop marks
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\CROP@@ulc{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \unitlength 1mm\thinlines
        \put(-10,0){\line(1,0){7}}
        \put(0,10){\line(0,-1){7}}
    \end{picture}%
}
\renewcommand*\CROP@@urc{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \unitlength 1mm\thinlines
        \put(10,0){\line(-1,0){7}}
        \put(0,10){\line(0,-1){7}}
    \end{picture}%
}
\renewcommand*\CROP@@llc{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \unitlength 1mm\thinlines
        \put(-10,0){\line(1,0){7}}
        \put(0,-10){\line(0,1){7}}
    \end{picture}%
}
\renewcommand*\CROP@@lrc{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \unitlength 1mm\thinlines
        \put(10,0){\line(-1,0){7}}
        \put(0,-10){\line(0,1){7}}
    \end{picture}%
}
\crop
\makeatother

% set up PDF page boxes
% all dimensions specified in big points with origin at lower left corner of
% media box
\pdfpageattr{
  % Media box is 230mm by 317mm
  /MediaBox [0.0 0.0 651.96850 898.58268]
  % Bleed box is 216mm by 303mm
  /BleedBox [19.84252 19.84252 632.12598 878.74016]
  % Trim box is A4 (210mm by 297mm)
  /TrimBox [28.34646 28.34646 623.62205 870.23622]
}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1}, width=216mm, height=303mm, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}]{example-image.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you, I am trying to fix the `Bleed box` in my document, I've raised the question yesterday, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504959/set-bleedbox-using-pdflatex can I get any advise for this? please.... I am contacting you, because your solution similar to my problem, but not able to fix it....

Answer (score 0):

just setting the physical printing paper width as width of the PDF to be included with the \includepdf works. stupid me...

```
\newcommand{\printingPaperWidth}{216mm}

\includepdf[pages={1}, width=\printingPaperWidth, pagecommand={
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Referenz: Gal Gadot} \label{img:2018050601}\glsadd{motivational:GadotGal} \thispagestyle{empty}
}]{img/GalGadot_Schulterblick.pdf} %2-7,2,4,{},6
```

note that \paperwidth does not work (not that stupid me...) because that indeed gets the logical document's width

is there some way provided by LaTeX or the crop package to get that physical paper width without setting it twice (once is necessary of course in order to tell crop how much margin will be cut of by the print service)?