# How can I write a different /BleedBox for odd and even pages

Tags: pdftex, expansion

For the book to be published, I need to provide a different `/BleedBox` for odd and even pages. I tried to achieve this through `\pdfpageattr` which works well if only used once in my document, for even/odd page separation, I tried:

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot,10pt,paper=155mm:230mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[frame,width=169.8truemm,height=247.4truemm,cam,pdftex,cross]{crop}
\setlength{\voffset}{7.4mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{7.4mm}

\usepackage{ifthen,everypage}

\newcommand{\checkthatpage}[2]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
    {#1}%
    {#2}%
}%

\AddEverypageHook{\checkthatpage{An even page with no bleed left\noexpand\pdfpageattr{
            /TrimBox [20.976 28.346 460.346 680.315]
            /BleedBox [29.480 19.843 460.346 688.819]
    }}{An odd page with no bleed right\noexpand\pdfpageattr{
    /TrimBox [20.976 28.346 460.346 680.315]
    /BleedBox [20.976 19.843 468.850 688.819]
}}}

\begin{document}
This page is:
\newpage
This page is:
\newpage
This page is:
\newpage
This page is:
\newpage
\end{document}
```

However with this appraoch I am not getting any boxes into the output at all, I checked the PDF in an editor. What am I doing wrong? Is it due to expansion, or because of the macro position? There is no `/BleedBox` in the output at all.

**Bonus question**: Can I automate the calculation by just setting an odd/even relative bleed margin and get the `/BleedBox` from the settings for the `crop` package?

**Answer to bonus question**: With the help of @Ulrike Fischer in her answer and some additions from other questions and answers, I was able to figure this out by myself, see my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use atbegshi. If needed switch the odd/even values, I copied the values into the pages. Be aware that you are overwriting the \pdfpageattr register. If other parts of your code write to it too, the content will be lost.

```
% uncompress the pdf: 
\pdfcompresslevel0
\pdfobjcompresslevel0

\documentclass[numbers=noenddot,10pt,paper=155mm:230mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[frame,width=169.8truemm,height=247.4truemm,cam,pdftex,cross]{crop}
\setlength{\voffset}{7.4mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{7.4mm}

\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout
{\ifodd\value{page}
   \pdfpageattr{
            /TrimBox [20.976 28.346 460.346 680.315]
            /BleedBox [29.480 19.843 460.346 688.819]
     }
 \else 
    \pdfpageattr{
      /TrimBox [20.976 28.346 460.346 680.315]
      /BleedBox [20.976 19.843 468.850 688.819]
      }
 \fi     
}

\begin{document}
This page is: /TrimBox [20.976 28.346 460.346 680.315] /BleedBox [29.480 19.843 460.346 688.819] 
\newpage
This page is: /TrimBox [20.976 28.346 460.346 680.315] /BleedBox [20.976 19.843 468.850 688.819] 
\newpage
This page is: /TrimBox [20.976 28.346 460.346 680.315] /BleedBox [29.480 19.843 460.346 688.819] 
\newpage
This page is: /TrimBox [20.976 28.346 460.346 680.315] /BleedBox [20.976 19.843 468.850 688.819] 
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this version of your MWE.

```
% bleedboxprob.tex SE 546714

\documentclass[numbers=noenddot,10pt,paper=155mm:230mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[frame,width=169.8truemm,height=247.4truemm,cam,pdftex,cross]{crop}
\setlength{\voffset}{7.4mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{7.4mm}

\usepackage{ifthen,everypage}

\newcommand{\checkthatpage}[2]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
    {#1}%
    {#2}%
}%

\AddEverypageHook{\checkthatpage{An even page with no bleed left\noexpand\pdfpageattr{
            /TrimBox [20.976 28.346 460.346 680.315]
            /BleedBox [29.480 19.843 460.346 688.819]
    }}{An odd page with no bleed right\noexpand\pdfpageattr{
    /TrimBox [20.976 28.346 460.346 680.315]
    /BleedBox [20.976 19.843 468.850 688.819]
}}}

\begin{document}
This page is: \checkthatpage{odd}{even}
\newpage
This page is: \checkthatpage{odd}{even}
\newpage
This page is: \checkthatpage{odd}{even}
\newpage
This page is: \checkthatpage{odd}{even}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

There seems to be a contradiction in the output. Perhaps you would want to check your code.

Comment: Hi @Peter Wilson: If I need to call `\checkthatpage` on every page, then there is no purpose in setting the `\AddEverypageHook`. I need this for a 190 page document and I cannot manually set the PDF output there.

Comment: @TobiBS If you ran my MWE you would have seen that my `checkthatpage{odd}{even}` gave different results to your `\AddEveryPageHook` I was not suggesting that you put `\checkthatpage` on every page but take a look at what your `\AddEverypageHook` does.

Comment: Hi @Peter Wilson, thanks for pointing that out, but this was not my main issue. The main issue was, that while the visible text was sent to the PDF, the `\pdfpageattr` was not sent to the PDF for whatever reason. However @Ulrike Fischer provided a working solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

With the answer of @Ulrike Fischer, which I accepted and the solutions given in [How can I set the PDF TrimBox dynamically (with a macro) and compiler independent?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297573/how-can-i-set-the-pdf-trimbox-dynamically-with-a-macro-and-compiler-independen) and [Set BleedBox using PDFLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504959/set-bleedbox-using-pdflatex) I also came up with an answer for my bonus question, which allows automatic computation of the boxes based on existing and given values. `\hoffset`, `\voffset`, `\stockwidth` and `\stockheight` are values from `crop`. Additionally you can define `\outsidebleed` which is the additional margin on the outside edges of a mounted page.

Maybe it is of help to someone looking here in the future.

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot,10pt,paper=155mm:230mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[frame,width=169.8truemm,height=247.4truemm,cam,pdftex,cross]{crop}
\setlength{\voffset}{7.4mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{7.4mm}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

%% define bleed for the three outside edges
\dim_new:N \outsidebleed 
\dim_set:Nn \outsidebleed { 3mm }

%% values for the Trim box on all pages
\tl_new:N \trim_box
\tl_set:Nx \trim_box {
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \hoffset} \space 
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \stockheight - \paperheight - \voffset} \space
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \paperwidth + \hoffset } \space
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \stockheight - \voffset }
}

%% values for the Bleed box on odd pages
\tl_new:N \bleed_box_odd
\tl_set:Nx \bleed_box_odd {
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \hoffset } \space 
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \stockheight - \paperheight - \voffset } \space
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \paperwidth + \hoffset + \outsidebleed } \space
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \stockheight - \voffset + \outsidebleed }
}

%% values for the Bleed box on even pages
\tl_new:N \bleed_box_even
\tl_set:Nx \bleed_box_even {
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \hoffset - \outsidebleed } \space 
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n {  \stockheight - \paperheight - \voffset - \outsidebleed } \space
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \paperwidth + \hoffset } \space
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \stockheight - \voffset + \outsidebleed }
}

%% page attribute for odd pages
\tl_new:N \pageattr_odd
\tl_set:Nx \pageattr_odd {
    /TrimBox \space [ \trim_box ]
    \space
    /BleedBox \space [ \bleed_box_odd ]
}

%% page attribute for even pages
\tl_new:N \pageattr_even
\tl_set:Nx \pageattr_even {
    /TrimBox \space [ \trim_box ]
    /BleedBox \space [ \bleed_box_even ]
}

%% command to set the page attribute
\NewDocumentCommand{\setpdfpageattreven}{}{\exp_args:Ne \pdfpageattr { \pageattr_even } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setpdfpageattrodd}{}{\exp_args:Ne \pdfpageattr { \pageattr_odd } }

%% just a macro to show some debug info
\NewDocumentCommand { \debuginfo } { } {
    \par\medskip\noindent
    pageattribute \space even: \\
    \mbox { \texttt { \pageattr_even } }
    \par\medskip\noindent
    pageattribute \space odd: \\
    \mbox { \texttt { \pageattr_odd } }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout
{\ifodd\value{page}
    \setpdfpageattrodd
    \else 
    \setpdfpageattreven
    \fi     
}

\begin{document}
\debuginfo
Test
\newpage
Test
\newpage
Test
\newpage
Test
\newpage
Test
\newpage
Test
\newpage
Test
\end{document}
```