# Trimbox not showing for full page floats using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, trimbox

My tags are follows (Thanks to `David Carlisle`: [How can I set the PDF TrimBox dynamically (with a macro) and compiler independent?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297573/how-can-i-set-the-pdf-trimbox-dynamically-with-a-macro-and-compiler-independen) and `David Purton` [Set BleedBox using PDFLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504959/set-bleedbox-using-pdflatex/505112?noredirect=1#comment1537567_505112))

```
%\pdfcompresslevel0
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% bleed value (keyval class option in real document)
\dim_new:N \g_@@_bleed_dim 
\dim_set:Nn \g_@@_bleed_dim { 3mm }

%% set page size (and other stuff in the real document)
\usepackage { geometry }
   \geometry { papersize = { 185mm , 245mm } }

%% set crop size
\usepackage [ center ] { crop }
   \CROP@size {
      \dim_eval:n { \paperwidth + 2 \g_@@_bleed_dim }
   } {
      \dim_eval:n { \paperheight + 2 \g_@@_bleed_dim }
   }

%% new variant
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { V }

% values for the rim box
\tl_new:N \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl
\tl_set:Nx \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl {
   \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:V \g_@@_bleed_dim \space 
   \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:V \g_@@_bleed_dim \space
   \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \paperwidth + \g_@@_bleed_dim } \space
   \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \paperheight + \g_@@_bleed_dim }
}

%% special for use with XeTeX
\tl_new:N \g_@@_trim_special_tl
\tl_set:Nx \g_@@_trim_special_tl {
   pdf: ~ put ~ @thispage ~
   << ~ /TrimBox \space [ \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl ] ~ >>
}

%% page attribute for use with LuaTeX and PDFTeX
\tl_new:N \g_@@_trim_pageattr_tl
\tl_set:Nx \g_@@_trim_pageattr_tl {
   /TrimBox \space [ \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl ]
}




%% command to set the specials for xetex
\cs_new:Npn \@@_special:n #1 {
   \AtBeginShipout { \immediate \special { #1 } }
   \immediate \special { #1 }
}

%% command to set the page attributes for pdftex/luatex
\cs_new:Npn \@@_pdfpageattr:n #1 {
   \pdfpageattr { #1 }
}

%% make a variants to make sure we get the expaned content
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \@@_special:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \@@_pdfpageattr:n { V }

%% [A] THIS DOES NOT WORK!
%% set the trim box according to engine
\bool_if:nTF { \sys_if_engine_luatex_p: || \sys_if_engine_pdftex_p: } {
   \@@_pdfpageattr:V \g_@@_trim_pageattr_tl
} {
   \sys_if_engine_xetex:TF {
      \usepackage{atbegshi}
      \@@_special:V \g_@@_trim_special_tl
   } { ERROR: UNKOWN MACHINE! }
}

%% just a macro to show some debug info
\NewDocumentCommand { \debuginfo } { } {
   \par\noindent
   Machine: ~ \texttt{ \c_sys_engine_str }

   \par\bigskip\noindent
   special: \\
   \mbox { \texttt { \g_@@_trim_special_tl } }

   \par\medskip\noindent
   pageattribute: \\
   \mbox { \texttt { \g_@@_trim_pageattr_tl } }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% [B] THIS WORKS!
%% for pdftex and luatex
%\pdfpageattr { /TrimBox [8.50392 8.50392 532.91336 702.99211] }
%% for xetex
%\usepackage{atbegshi}
%\AtBeginShipout { \special { pdf: put @thispage << /TrimBox [8.50392 8.50392 532.91336 702.99211] >> } }
%\special { pdf: put @thispage << /TrimBox [8.50392 8.50392 532.91336 702.99211] >> }

\begin{document}
\section*{Test Document}
\debuginfo \clearpage Just another page \ldots

\newpage

\begin{figure}[p!]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm using `XeLaTeX` above works fine and got `TrimBox` in all pages, but when a full page float comes then the `TrimBox` vanished, please suggest how to achieve that too... But the same works fine for all pages when using `PDFLaTeX`...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't know why it vanishes and I don't have the time to look. If you want the same trimbox on all pages you could use  `pdf: ~ put ~ @pages ~` instead. Or you try the new pdfmanagement:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdfmanagement_add:nnn{Page}{Trimbox}{[8.50392~8.50392~532.91336~702.99211]}
% or
%\pdfmanagement_add:nnn{Pages}{Trimbox}{[8.50392~8.50392~532.91336~702.99211]}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}


\section*{Test Document}
\clearpage Just another page \ldots

\newpage

\begin{figure}[p!]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This works with all engines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tested it and couldn't find the Trim box in all pages, my version is `This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 21.3) (preloaded format=xelatex 2021.9.6)  16 SEP 2021 12:11
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>`

Comment: Also, if I use `pdf: ~ put ~ @pages ~` instead of `pdf: ~ put ~ @thispage ~` in my definitions, then `TrimBox` not showing in all pages, please advise...

Comment: I tested with a current miktex and it worked fine `LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as Ulrike's answer, except I used your code as a base (and fixed the Trimbox→TrimBox typo in Ulrike's answer).

I suggest you do use the new `pdfmanagement` code, which currently works and will certainly be more reliable in the long term.

This works in all three engines with my tests:

```
\DocumentMetadata{uncompress}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% bleed value (keyval class option in real document)
\dim_new:N \g_@@_bleed_dim 
\dim_set:Nn \g_@@_bleed_dim { 3mm }

%% set page size (and other stuff in the real document)
\usepackage { geometry }
\geometry { papersize = { 185mm , 245mm } }

%% set crop size
\usepackage [ center ] { crop }
\CROP@size
  {
    \dim_eval:n { \paperwidth + 2 \g_@@_bleed_dim }
  }
  {
    \dim_eval:n { \paperheight + 2 \g_@@_bleed_dim }
  }

%% new variant
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { V }

% values for the TrimBox
\tl_new:N \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl
\tl_set:Nx \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl
  {
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:V \g_@@_bleed_dim \space
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:V \g_@@_bleed_dim \space
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \paperwidth + \g_@@_bleed_dim } \space
    \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n { \paperheight + \g_@@_bleed_dim }
  }

% set the TrimBox
\pdfmanagement_add:nnx
  { Page }
  { TrimBox }
  { [ \g_@@_trim_box_quadruple_tl ] }

\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\section*{Test Document}

\clearpage

Just another page \ldots

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[p!]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Much thanks for your reply, currently, I'm not in system, I'll confirm by tomorrow...Thanks

Comment: I received error as `Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \DocumentMetadata` and I'm using `XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 21.3)` Please advise

Comment: @MadyYuvi Your TeX distribution is too old. Upgrade MiKTeX in both admin and user mode