# Add indentation for printing

Tags: indentation, layout

I'm about to print my thesis (A4 size) and the publisher has requested me to extend   the size of each side of page in 3 mm, so the paper cutter can do its thing properly. I can't change the size of the whole project as it would ruin the lay out so, how could I add this extra size in all pages?

Just in case I haven't made myself understood, I attach a picture of the desired process from the current state (left) to the goal (right). Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try `\addtolength\oddsidemargin{3mm}\addtolength\evensidemargin{-3mm}`.  This also accounts for double sided printing.  If you are doing single sided, then you want both even and odd to be `+3mm`.

Comment: Thanks Steven, it's double sided but it's not working, apparently.

Comment: In what sense, "not working"?  Here's an MWE, where it kicks in on pages 3,4  `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-9]
\clearpage
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{30mm}\addtolength\evensidemargin{-30mm}
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}`

Comment: Perhaps `\geometry{bindingoffset=3mm}` from the eponymous package?

Comment: If you use KOMAscript, use BCOR=3mm. You may also look into the printer driver. At least Windows printer driver have an option to set binding correction when you print, and will just move the page sidewise with a given value.

Comment: Note that you need to extend the black box to the edge of your page still. The extra 3mm then gets trimmed off and no white gap will be left in case the trim is not quite right. It's not possible to answer this question unless you show us your document class and margin set up method.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455202/87678

Comment: @DavidPurton you're absolutely right. My description above is wrong because the white gap is not enough, the black box has to be extended too. However, the solution provided by StevenB.Segletes also makes that (my fault). Thank you all.