# Two images with background package

Tags: backgrounds

Good morning.
I'm using background package. I think that I follow the package istructions, but I have two questions:

1. The second image don't appear. Where I'm wrong?
2. It's possible to move number-page image up on text?
   Thank you.

Here the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength\columnsep{10mm}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=20mm]{image.pdf}
\end{figure}

\backgroundsetup{opacity=1,hshift=60,vshift=-5,angle=0,contents={\includegraphics[width=50mm]{image.pdf}}}

%page-number from istructions
\backgroundsetup{placement=top,angle=0,color=black!40,scale=4,hshift=60,vshift=-5,contents={-\thepage-}}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=10mm]{image.pdf}
\lipsum[1-2]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=10mm]{image.pdf}
\lipsum[1-2]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=10mm]{image.pdf}
\lipsum[1-2]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=10mm]{image.pdf}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use `\backgroundsetup` twice for the same page. This settings are not additive, the second command replaces the first.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this. But I have four or five images to insert in my page. Background package isn't good choice? There is another package to do this?

Comment: You can insert all images in one content declaration, e.g. by using a tabular or a tikzpicture there. You can also look at eso-pic, it allows additive declarations.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it is possible. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134717/3406

Comment: Your example is not an MWE. What's `image.pdf`?